# Google YouTube API vb.net references

Tags: vb.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am new to the Google oAuth and YouTube APIs.  I am trying to follow the examples at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet - specifically the Upload Video example.  I am working with VB.NET - visual studio 2013.  I have added the libraries via nuget.  When I add the import statements, I am getting Namespace or Type cannot be found for Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2, Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 and Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.  Google.Apis.Services, Upload and Util.Store work fine.  I suspect I am missing a reference somewhere, but I cannot find what to look for or add.  My project is in .Net 4.5.1.  I have references to Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Core and Google.Apis.PlatformServices.  From what I can tell, I need a reference to Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2, but I cannot find that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the libraries on nuget to reference.  Look for Google APIs Auth Client Library and Google.Apis.YouTube.vs Client Library in nuget.